# How can I stop FileUploadBase to create upload_temp_file on JBoss 7

Tags: java, file-upload, jboss, apache-commons

it's my first question to Stackoverflow :)

So, I have an Java Web application where I'm using JBoss 7.1 to run this app. In this app I have a servlet to upload one file to my application and I'm using this lib: `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.`

When I call the method `FileUploadBase.parseRequest`, a file called **upload_d77dbeb6_aa80_4d64_a112_2ea7c12c6ced_00000089.tmp** is created in `C:\Users\[server-machine]\AppData\Local\Temp` and the size is the same the original file that I uploaded into my application.

The file name is generated by the `FileUploadBase` and always increase plus five, like:

1. upload_d77...ced_00000089.tmp
2. upload_d77...ced_00000094.tmp
3. upload_d77...ced_00000099.tmp

bellow follow the code of parseRequest method, the file is created when the **while loop** is finished.

```
public List<FileItem> parseRequest(RequestContext ctx)
        throws FileUploadException {
    List<FileItem> items = new ArrayList<FileItem>();
    boolean successful = false;
    try {
        FileItemIterator iter = getItemIterator(ctx);
        FileItemFactory fac = getFileItemFactory();
        if (fac == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("No FileItemFactory has been set.");
        }
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            final FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            // Don't use getName() here to prevent an InvalidFileNameException.
            final String fileName = ((FileItemIteratorImpl.FileItemStreamImpl) item).name;
            FileItem fileItem = fac.createItem(item.getFieldName(), item.getContentType(),
                                               item.isFormField(), fileName);
            items.add(fileItem);
            try {
                Streams.copy(item.openStream(), fileItem.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (FileUploadIOException e) {
                throw (FileUploadException) e.getCause();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOFileUploadException(format("Processing of %s request failed. %s",
                                                       MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, e.getMessage()), e);
            }
            final FileItemHeaders fih = item.getHeaders();
            fileItem.setHeaders(fih);
        }
        successful = true;
        return items;
    } catch (FileUploadIOException e) {
        throw (FileUploadException) e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FileUploadException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (!successful) {
            for (FileItem fileItem : items) {
                try {
                    fileItem.delete();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // ignore it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debuged the temp_file is created exactly when debug was stopped on `successful = true;`

Is there any way at Jboss to disable the file creation orsome parameter to set up?

bellow follow my code where I invoke the `parseRequest`

```
try {
            List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            upload.setProgressListener(listener);

            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `DefaultItemFactory` but this class is deprecated then I used `DiskFileItemFactory` instead.

`DiskFileItemFactory` clean temp files using the Gabage Collector from java.io

> **File Cleaning Tracker:** 
>   Keeps track of files awaiting deletion, and deletes them when an associated
>   marker object is reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Even so, I had to do a Job to delete old file, because **File Cleaning Tracker** 
just delete temp file that was tracked, old temp file wasn't tracked so it'd never been delete by GC.

Thanks Alex, I just figured out because your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not JBoss that does it. When you use

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
```

you instruct your application to store files on disk.

You can use [DefaultItemFactory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/DefaultFileItemFactory.html%20DefaultItemFactory) instead that

> ...creates FileItem instances which keep their content either in memory, for smaller items, or in a temporary file on disk, for larger items. The size threshold, above which content will be stored on disk, is configurable, as is the directory in which temporary files will be created.